# Pandas not able to merge the file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, data-science

I am trying to merge two files, I am supplying them headers as they are not able to pick up headers when I merge them using concatenate , I get an error when I am trying to drop a column......
ValueError: labels ['lh.aparc.a2009s.meancurv'] not contained in axis
Therefore I am trying the below method.....

The headers are important because I want to compute average, mean etc on the basis of these headers....

But currently, the result file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKUlu.jpg)

CSV 1[CSV1 looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KySPA.jpg) CSV 2 looks the same just with rh

```
# !/bin/bash
ls -d */ | sed -e "s/\///g" | grep -v "Results" | grep -v "Output">> subjects.txt;
module unload freesurfer
module load freesurfer/5.3.0
module load python
export SUBJECTS_DIR=/N/u/shrechak/Karst/GENFL_FREESURFER53_KARST_RES
source $FREESURFER_HOME/FreeSurferEnv.sh

aparcstats2table --hemi lh --subjectsfile=subjects.txt --parc aparc.a2009s --meas meancurv --tablefile lh.a2009s.meancurv.txt
aparcstats2table --hemi rh --subjectsfile=subjects.txt --parc aparc.a2009s --meas meancurv --tablefile rh.a2009s.meancurv.txt

for f in *.txt; do
    mv "$f" "${f%.txt}.csv"
done


python <<END_OF_PYTHON

import csv

import pandas as pd

names= ["meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_frontomargin_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_occipital_inf_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_paracentral_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_subcentral_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_transv_frontopol_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_cingul-ant_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_cingul-Mid-Ant_meancurv",
"lh_G_and_S_cingul-Mid-Post_meancurv",
"lh_G_cingul-Post-dorsal_meancurv",
"lh_G_cingul-Post-ventral_meancurv",
"lh_G_cuneus_meancurv",
"lh_G_front_inf-Opercular_meancurv",
"lh_G_front_inf-orbital_meancurv",
"lh_G_front_inf-Triangul_meancurv",
"lh_G_front_middle_meancurv",
"lh_G_front_sup_meancurv",
"lh_G_Ins_lg_and_S_cent_ins_meancurv",
"lh_G_insular_short_meancurv",
"lh_G_occipital_middle_meancurv",
"lh_G_occipital_sup_meancurv",
"lh_G_oc-temp_lat-fusifor_meancurv",
"lh_G_oc-temp_med-Lingual_meancurv",
"lh_G_oc-temp_med-Parahip_meancurv",
"lh_G_orbital_meancurv",
"lh_G_pariet_infoangular_meancurv",
"lh_G_pariet_infSupramar_meancurv",
"lh_G_parietal_sup_meancurv",
"lh_G_postcentral_meancurv",
"lh_G_precentral_meancurv",
"lh_G_precuneus_meancurv",
"lh_G_rectus_meancurv",
"lh_G_subcallosal_meancurv",
"lh_G_temp_sup-G_T_transv_meancurv",
"lh_G_temp_sup-Lateral_meancurv",
"lh_G_temp_sup-Plan_polar_meancurv",
"lh_G_temp_supPlan_tempo_meancurv",
"lh_G_temporal_inf_meancurv",
"lh_G_temporal_middle_meancurv",
"lh_Lat_Fis-ant-Horizont_meancurv",
"lh_Lat_Fis-ant-Vertical_meancurv",
"lh_Lat_Fispost_meancurv",
"lh_Pole_occipital_meancurv",
"lh_Pole_temporal_meancurv",
"lh_S_calcarine_meancurv",
"lh_S_central_meancurv",
"lh_S_cingulMarginalis_meancurv",
"lh_S_circular_insula_ant_meancurv",
"lh_S_circular_insula_inf_meancurv",
"lh_S_circular_insula_sup_meancurv",
"lh_S_collat_transv_ant_meancurv",
"lh_S_collat_transv_post_meancurv",
"lh_S_front_inf_meancurv",
"lh_S_front_middle_meancurv",
"lh_S_front_sup_meancurv",
"lh_S_interm_prim-Jensen_meancurv",
"lh_S_intrapariet_and_P_trans_meancurv",
"lh_S_oc_middle_and_Lunatus_meancurv",
"lh_S_oc_sup_and_transversal_meancurv",
"lh_S_occipital_ant_meancurv",
"lh_S_oc-temp_lat_meancurv",
"lh_S_oc-temp_med_and_Lingual_meancurv",
"lh_S_orbital_lateral_meancurv",
"lh_S_orbital_med-olfact_meancurv",
"lh_S_orbital-H_Shaped_meancurv",
"lh_S_parieto_occipital_meancurv",
"lh_S_pericallosal_meancurv",
"lh_S_postcentral_meancurv",
"lh_S_precentral-inf-part_meancurv",
"lh_S_precentral-sup-part_meancurv",
"lh_S_suborbital_meancurv",
"lh_S_subparietal_meancurv",
"lh_S_temporal_inf_meancurv",
"lh_S_temporal_sup_meancurv",
"lh_S_temporal_transverse_meancurv"]

df1 = pd.read_csv('lh.a2009s.meancurv.csv', header = None, names = names)

names1 = ["meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_frontomargin_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_occipital_inf_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_paracentral_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_subcentral_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_transv_frontopol_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_cingul-Ant_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_cingul-Mid-Ant_meancurv",
"rh_G_and_S_cingul-Mid-Post_meancurv",
"rh_G_cingul-Post-dorsal_meancurv",
"rh_G_cingul-Post-ventral_meancurv",
"rh_G_cuneus_meancurv",
"rh_G_front_inf-Opercular_meancurv",
"rh_G_front_inf-Orbital_meancurv",
"rh_G_front_inf-Triangul_meancurv",
"rh_G_front_middle_meancurv",
"rh_G_front_sup_meancurv",
"rh_G_Ins_lg_and_S_cent_ins_meancurv",
"rh_G_insular_short_meancurv",
"rh_G_occipital_middle_meancurv",
"rh_G_occipital_sup_meancurv",
"rh_G_oc-temp_lat-fusifor_meancurv",
"rh_G_oc-temp_med-Lingual_meancurv",
"rh_G_oc-temp_med-Parahip_meancurv",
"rh_G_orbital_meancurv",
"rh_G_pariet_inf-Angular_meancurv",
"rh_G_pariet_inf-Supramar_meancurv",
"rh_G_parietal_sup_meancurv",
"rh_G_postcentral_meancurv",
"rh_G_precentral_meancurv",
"rh_G_precuneus_meancurv",
"rh_G_rectus_meancurv",
"rh_G_subcallosal_meancurv",
"rh_G_temp_sup-G_T_transv_meancurv",
"rh_G_temp_sup-Lateral_meancurv",
"rh_G_temp_sup-Plan_polar_meancurv",
"rh_G_temp_sup-Plan_tempo_meancurv",
"rh_G_temporal_inf_meancurv",
"rh_G_temporal_middle_meancurv",
"rh_Lat_Fis-ant-Horizont_meancurv",
"rh_Lat_Fis-ant-Vertical_meancurv",
"rh_Lat_Fis-post_meancurv",
"rh_Pole_occipital_meancurv",
"rh_Pole_temporal_meancurv",
"rh_S_calcarine_meancurv",
"rh_S_central_meancurv",
"rh_S_cingulMarginalis_meancurv",
"rh_S_circular_insula_ant_meancurv",
"rh_S_circular_insula_inf_meancurv",
"rh_S_circular_insula_sup_meancurv",
"rh_S_collat_transv_ant_meancurv",
"rh_S_collat_transv_post_meancurv",
"rh_S_front_inf_meancurv",
"rh_S_front_middle_meancurv",
"rh_S_front_sup_meancurv",
"rh_S_interm_prim-Jensen_meancurv",
"rh_S_intrapariet_and_P_trans_meancurv",
"rh_S_oc_middle_and_Lunatus_meancurv",
"rh_S_oc_sup_and_transversal_meancurv",
"rh_S_occipital_ant_meancurv",
"rh_S_oc-temp_lat_meancurv",
"rh_S_oc-temp_med_and_Lingual_meancurv",
"rh_S_orbital_lateral_meancurv",
"rh_S_orbital_med-olfact_meancurv",
"rh_S_orbital-H_Shaped_meancurv",
"rh_S_parieto_occipital_meancurv",
"rh_S_pericallosal_meancurv",
"rh_S_postcentral_meancurv",
"rh_S_precentral-inf-part_meancurv",
"rh_S_precentral-sup-part_meancurv",
"rh_S_suborbital_meancurv",
"rh_S_subparietal_meancurv",
"rh_S_temporal_inf_meancurv",
"rh_S_temporal_sup_meancurv",
"rh_S_temporal_transverse_meancurv"
]

df2 = pd.read_csv('rh.a2009s.meancurv.csv', header = None, names = names1)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='meancurv', how='outer')

result.to_csv('result.csv')





END_OF_PYTHON

echo "goodbye!";
```

Comment: What do the CSVs look like?  Do they have headers?

Comment: Please include a minimal example of the csv file(s) - the first few rows should be sufficient.

Comment: posted an edit to the question to include CSV file

Comment: There's your problem - if you say `header = None` then it takes the first row of the CSV as just another row of data.  You really want to skip that first row, then pull the rest of the data.

Comment: So i should remove header = None?
& then it will take my names as header?

Comment: gives me an error when i pass header = names
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: Don't even bother with the `header =` bit. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to skip the first row and only pull the data parts.

Here's an MCVE.

**Code:**

```
import io
import pandas as pd

csv1 = io.StringIO(u'''
a,b,c
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv1, names = ['d','e','f'], skiprows = [1])

print df
```

**Output:**

```
   d  e  f
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: The names do not appear columnwise ......They appear in the first two rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can **merge two files together file keeping the headers from the one of the files after merging**.

---

*Say you're keeping files in a list 'files':*

```
files = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv'] #keep files here
finalDF = pd.DataFrame() #this is an empty dataframe
for file in files:
    thisDF = pd.read_csv(file)
    finalDF = finalDF.append(thisDF, ignore_index=True)
```

**Now if you want try these two lines:**

*say you want to check the header using a simple print head()*

```
print finalDF.head()
```

*and if you want to write this merged data frame to a csv file*

```
finalDF.to_csv('merged-file.csv', encoding="utf-8", index=False)
```

- for skipping rows are you trying to skip rows after or before
  merging? let me know and i can try helping with that too.

---

### Example:

**file1.csv:**

```
,column1,column2,column3,column4,Date,Device,sample_site
2,14888,0.060011931,248084,13.40535464,3/15/2017,DESKTOP,http://www.example1.com
11,1358,0.033212679,40888,7.465099785,3/15/2017,MOBILE,http://www.example2.com
23,130,0.02998155,4336,8.337638376,3/15/2017,TABLET,http://www.example3.com
```

**file2.csv:**

```
,column1,column2,column3,column4,Date,Device,sample_site
35,2685,0.034564882,77680,10.97812822,3/15/2017,DESKTOP,https://www.example4.com
45,280,0.026197605,10688,7.801272455,3/15/2017,MOBILE,https://www.example5.com
54,24,0.022878932,1049,8.202097235,3/15/2017,TABLET,https://www.example6.com
```

**merged-file.csv:**

```
Unnamed: 0,column1,column2,column3,column4,Date,Device,sample_site
2,14888,0.060011931,248084,13.40535464,3/15/2017,DESKTOP,http://www.example1.com
11,1358,0.033212679,40888,7.465099785,3/15/2017,MOBILE,http://www.example2.com
23,130,0.02998155,4336,8.337638376,3/15/2017,TABLET,http://www.example3.com
35,2685,0.034564882,77680,10.97812822,3/15/2017,DESKTOP,https://www.example4.com
45,280,0.026197605,10688,7.801272455,3/15/2017,MOBILE,https://www.example5.com
54,24,0.022878932,1049,8.202097235,3/15/2017,TABLET,https://www.example6.com
```

Reply:

Are you trying to merge data based on a column? In that case you can concat or merge with join based on an axis.

Say for example: 
`pd.concat([df1, df2]) #add axis and join type if necessary`.

Here's the documentation to help you understand: [merging and concat in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Comment: Hi Harsh,
This does merge the file but I need the file merged Columnwise......
This is I am guessing merging it row-wise....Because I get all the 'lh' headers in the first two rows and all the values under them & I am trying to delete columns after I merge the file

Comment: are you trying to merge data based on a column? In that case you can concat or merge with join based on an axis. Say for example: pd.concat([df1, df2]) #add axis and join type if necessary. Here's the documentation to help you understand: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html